# While statement and boolean OR in Python

Tags: python, while-loop, boolean

```
y=''
print 'y= nothing'
y = raw_input('-->')
while y!='O' or y!='X':
    print 'You have to choose either X or O'
    y = raw_input('-->')
print 'Loop exited'
print y
```

Could anyone explain why the above code doesn't run properly in python?

I assume that any time the user inputs something except 'X' or 'O' he gets the message and the prompt for input. But as soon as the user provides either 'X' or 'O', the loop should exit. But it doesn't... Could you, guys help? I am a novice in python...

Comment: Use `and` instead of `or` for your while loop.

Comment: Your condition is the same as `not (y=='O' and y=='X')`, y cannot equals to two different char. So `y=='O' and y=='X'` is always `False`, and then `not (y=='O' and y=='X')`is always `True`. I think what you want is `y!='O' and y!='X'`.

Comment: @Serjik that logic is not the same as what the author wants. I think OP wants to *not* enter the loop when `y` is equal to `'O'` or `'X'`.

Comment: @Jerrybibo Exactly, you got it !))) Sorry if my explanation was not that clear. I want not to enter the loop if Y = X or Y = O.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A different way of doing this is to use a `while True` and a `break` statement:

```
while True:
    y = raw_input('-->')

    if  y in ['O', 'X']:
        break
    print 'You have to choose either X or O'

print 'Loop exited'
print y
```

For example:

```
-->a
You have to choose either X or O
-->b
You have to choose either X or O
-->c
You have to choose either X or O
-->O
Loop exited
O
```

This avoids needing to have two input statements.

Comment: Thank you ) I was blind writing it) You are 100% right)

Answer (score 2):

There are several fixes to this erroneous logic flow. One was already mentioned by @Aanchal Sharma by having two `!=`'s and an `and` within the while loop like so:

```
while y != 'O' and y != 'X':
```

An alternate solution is to use `in` which I personally find more readable:

```
while y not in ['X', 'O']:
    print 'You have to choose either X or O'
    y = raw_input('--> ')
```

Hope this helped!

Answer (score 1):

```
y=''
print 'y= nothing'
y = raw_input('-->')
while (y!='O' and y!='X'):
    print 'You have to choose either X or O'
    y = raw_input('-->')
print 'Loop exited'
print y
```

Use 'and' condition not 'or'. In your case, `y` will always be either not-equal to 'O' or not-equal to 'X'. It can't be equal to both at the same time.

Comment: If `y` is 'O', then the loop should exit because it says 'You have to choose either X or O'. The loop is supposed to continue only till `y` is not 'X' or 'O'.

Comment: @anuragal I think you are misunderstanding what author wants.

Comment: @AanchalSharma Thank you. You are right. In my erroneous piece I always had Y !=1 or Y !=2 :) that was funny. What to say....newbie:) Appreciate your help.